# Filling Missing Data

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, data-cleaning

I have a large data set that follows the same trends as below:

```
# A tibble: 8 × 3
   Code Letter Count
  <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>
1     1 A      0.956
2     1 B      0.976
3     1 C      0.838
4     1 D      0.559
5     1 E      0.947
6     1 F      0.765
7     1 G      0.817
8     1 H      0.634
```

The problem is every so often some of the data is incomplete as below

```
# A tibble: 7 × 3
   Code Letter  Count
  <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
1     2 A      0.751 
2     2 B      0.650 
3     2 C      0.605 
4     2 E      0.0693
5     2 F      0.247 
6     2 G      0.488 
7     2 H      0.166
```

As you can see Code 2, Letter D is missing. I want to add in a row to complete this data to look like below:

```
# A tibble: 8 × 3
   Code Letter  Count
  <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
1     2 A      0.751 
2     2 B      0.650 
3     2 C      0.605 
4     2 D      0     
5     2 E      0.0693
6     2 F      0.247 
7     2 G      0.488 
8     2 H      0.166
```

There is hundreds rows of this data, so manually adding this isn't on the cards, is there any way to code this?

Thanks

Comment: See `?tidyr::complete`. Something like `complete(your_data, Code, Letter, fill = list(Count = 0)` will probably work.

Comment: I don think this works because complete is looking for gaps in my data but there aren’t gaps per say, as there is no NAs. 

The code would have to know to look for A -> H and fill gaps where a letter is missing?

Comment: I don't know why you think `complete` is looking for gaps in your data--it is not. Maybe you're confusing it with `tidyr::fill`? Give it a try on a simple example: `df = data.frame(Code = c(1, 1, 2), Letter = c('A', 'B', 'A'), Count = c(3, 4, 5))`, then the code in my first comment works perfectly. As the `?complete` help page says, it will "find all unique combinations" of `Code` and `Letter`. Give it a try before you say it doesn't work!

Comment: complete() would work if there was a code for which the absent letter was present. if thats not guaranteed its best not to use complete, but to use ones knowledge of what the full set would be to form a `spine` of expected data, and do a left_join from it, the gaps will naturally show as NA's and can be adjusted to zero as needed.

Comment: `# setup 
(df <-  data.frame(Code = 1:8, Letter = letters[1:8]))
(df_miss_d <- filter(df,
                    Letter != "d"))



# impossible to solve without knowing that there should be a d ...
# here we are explicit about what is expected
define_expected <- data.frame(Letter = letters[1:8])

# we join the expected to what has missing content, and fill the gap with 0
(df_fill_d <- left_join(define_expected,
                       df_miss_d) |> replace_na(replace = list("Code"=0)))`